# How to fix runtime error and remove double for abstract class in java?

Tags: java, class

My program asks to define an abstract class which contains:

- 3 protected instance variables: topLeft (of type java.awt.Point), width (of type int) and height (of type int)
- A default (or "no-argument" or "no-arg") constructor that construct a shape with default values: topLeft = (0, 0), width=0, and height=0
- An overloaded constructor that constructs a shape with the given values.
- An overridden toString() method that returns a string description of the instance in the format "(x, y) width x height"
- The accessor and mutator methods: getX(), getY(), setX(), setY(), getHeight()...

  - A move() method that moves the topLeft point by 1 in X-direction and 2 in y-direction
  - An abstract draw method that "draws" the shape by its position, width and height.

I have tried putting "int" instead of double but had an error saying cant be converted.

This is done so far

```
      import java.awt.*;

      abstract class SimpleMovingShape {

         protected Point topLeft;
         protected int width;
         protected int height;

         public SimpleMovingShape() {
            topLeft = new Point(0, 0);
            width = 0;
            height = 0;
         }


        public SimpleMovingShape(Point topLeft, int width, int height) {
            this.topLeft = topLeft;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
         }

        public double getX() {
            return topLeft.getX();
        }

        public double getY() {
            return topLeft.getY();
       }

        public void setX(double x) {
            topLeft.setLocation(x, topLeft.getY());
        }

        public void setY(double y) {
            topLeft.setLocation(topLeft.getX(), y);
        }

        public void move() {
            topLeft.setLocation(getX() + 1, getY() + 2);
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
       }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
       }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
       }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
       }

       public void setTopLeft(Point topLeft) {
           this.topLeft = topLeft;
       }

       public Point getTopLeft() {
           return topLeft;
       }

       public abstract void draw();

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "(" + getX() + "," + getY() + ") " + getWidth() + " X " 
           + getHeight();
      }
      }
```

For the tester

```
    SimpleMovingShape r2 = new SimpleMovingRectangle(new Point(10, 20), 
    20, 20);
    System.out.println(r2.getX());
    System.out.println(r2.getY());
```

The output shows `10.0     20.0`
where the expected output is `10     20`

For the tester this shows runtime error `SimpleMovingRectangle r1= new SimpleMovingRectangle();r1.move();
             System.out.printf("(%d, %d)", r1.getX(), r1.getY());`

```
   ***Runtime error***
   Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: 
   d != java.lang.Double
    at 
  java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at 
  java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at __Tester__.runTests(__Tester__.java:86)
    at __Tester__.main(__Tester__.java:80)
```

Comment: the output type of getX and getY is double! change the getter and setter for X and Y to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public int getX() {
            double dbl = topLeft.getX().doubleValue();
            return (int) dbl;
        }

        public int getY() {
            double dbl = topLeft.getY().doubleValue();
            return (int) dbl;
       }

        public void setX(int x) {
            topLeft.setLocation(x, topLeft.getY());
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            topLeft.setLocation(topLeft.getX(), y);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but i did try it before and it showed cant be converted .. incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Comment: Point holds its values as double. These have to be converted to int. The code above is changed.

Comment: I really hoped it work but it keeps saying "double cannot be dereferenced" ;(

Comment: I don't know why it's just generating output as double. Even though if i change all the methods as int

Comment: Ok i fixed it .. for get method topLeft.x is required.

Comment: If the answer is correct and solves the problem you can upvote.